# Java create random array size or length

Tags: java

In my application I must use one array with random size or length, for example

```
String[] SHS;

SHS   = new String[5];
/* or */
SHS   = new String[10];
```

now I'm trying to have this defining a custom function to define a random array size,

```
private String[] SHS;

public void setDay(String[] day) {
    SHS = new String[day.length];
    SHS = day;
}
```

for filling this array, I'm using this function:

```
private String[] setRange(int min, int max) {
    final String[] values = new String[max];
    for (int i = min - 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        values[i] = String.valueOf((i + 1));
    }
    return values;
}
```

but I get error when I'm trying to use `setDay( setRange(1,5) )` after `setDay( setRange(1,15) )` action. I get this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: What index does the error stack trace provides you. i.e. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : ?`

Comment: i am not getting any error while running your code as you said...

Comment: I just ran this code and didn't get any error. Did you miss some code out?

Comment: It would help if you check which line throws the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more obvious to pass an int in the setDay function to define the size of the array instead of an array? `public void setDay(int newLength) {SHS = new String[newLength];`

Comment: The code in the "setDay" méthod has no sense : you're instantiating an array, put it in the variable and replace it with the day array : "new String[day.length]" is useless.

Comment: It's hard to see what the OP wants to achieve with this code anyway imo. Also the naming is off, since the function to fill the array is called setRange(). Very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compiled the above to this class but it gets to print the sentence meaning the error is elsewhere in your code.

```
public class SOArrays {

    private String[] SHS;

    private void setDay(String[] day) {
       SHS = new String[day.length];
       SHS = day;
    }

    private String[] setRange(int min, int max) {
        final String[] values = new String[max];
        for (int i = min - 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        values[i] = String.valueOf((i + 1));
    }
    return values;
    }

    public void process(){
        setDay( setRange(1,5) );

        System.out.print("Finished without errors.");

     }

     public static void main(String[] args){

         new SOArrays().process();
     }
    }
```